# "Property access is not allowed yet" warning when using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, xdebug

I'm trying to make a log in system by using `AES_ENCRYPT()` to encode my password. But I have some warning from **xdebug** when trying to implement these codes:

```
...
$key = 'd0gis=SUPER-cute';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users2` WHERE username = ? AND pwd = AES_ENCRYPT(?, ?)";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $password, $key);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
...
```

When the debugger meets line 8 or `$stmt->prepare($sql);`, 6 same warning tables from **xdebug** says:

> (!) Warning: main(): Property access is not allowed yet in D:\xampp\htdocs\learnphp\includes\authenticate_mysqli.inc.php on line 8

The error property in `$stmt` is empty and I have no real problem, but I just want to know what cause this warning messages to appear.

Googled this warning message but didn't find any solution:

1. [UPDATE query with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056202/update-query-with-prepared-statements)
2. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.param-count.php

Comment: Why are you using `stmt_init()`? I've never seen that used before. Usually it's `$db->prepare(...)` directly.

Comment: I follow an [example](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php#example-1788) in php.net

Comment: That's odd because there's [other documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) that suggests you can call `prepare` directly on the link you have, and I've always seen it done that way.

Comment: Please see my answer for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870315/mysqli-property-access-is-not-allowed-yet/33469517#33469517 (dupe question, not sure how to flag it as such though)

Comment: maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377030/mysqli-xdebug-breakpoint-after-closing-statment-result-in-many-warnings

Comment: The second link in your question claims to address this exact issue: "To prevent this, always ensure that the return value of the prepare statement is true before accessing these properties." http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.param-count.php#89490

Answer (score 3):

Your mysql connection was probably not established. After `mysqli::__construct()` you have to check [`mysqli::$connect_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php), which was broken for some PHP versions:

> The mysqli->connect_error property only works properly as of PHP versions 5.2.9 and 5.3.0. Use the mysqli_connect_error() function if compatibility with earlier PHP versions is required.

See the connection boiler plate from the documentation of [`mysqli::__construct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/*
 * Use this instead of $connect_error if you need to ensure
 * compatibility with PHP versions prior to 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I believe the issue I describe below is the cause of the issue the OP describes, however since the problem I describe in my answer does not produce the exact same error message, I am no longer sure this is the best answer.

Also, I noticed this from the PHP docs comment section:

> This parameter (and presumably any other parameter in mysqli_stmt)
>   will raise an error with the message "Property access is not allowed
>   yet" if the statement was not prepared properly, or not prepared at
>   all.
>
> To prevent this, always ensure that the return value of the "prepare"
>   statement is true before accessing these properties.

Original answer:
This warning occurs when you try to evaluate certain objects (an instance of a class) as a string.

Your debugger/IDE is trying to evaluate one of your variables ($stmt), maybe in a watch list or call stack, and it cannot be evaluated as a string.

If you do `print_r` on the variable you will get the same error, because PHP cannot turn it into a string.

In your case, it is the $stmt that PHP cannot turn into a string.

Put this code on line 7 and you will see the error there:

```
print_r($stmt);
```

Somewhat side note: I never had this issue before recently.  Lately I've been getting it a lot.  Why doesn't php just skip the inaccessible properties and print the rest?  I believe it has to do with the scope of the properties or the use of getters/setters but I am not quite sure yet.  I will update when I figure that part out.

**from the official PHP documentation:**
(http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

> The __toString() method allows a class to decide how it will react
>   when it is treated like a string. For example, what echo $obj; will
>   print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal
>   E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR level error is emitted...
>
> ...It is worth noting that before PHP 5.2.0 the __toString() method
>   was only called when it was directly combined with echo or print.
>   Since PHP 5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in printf()
>   with %s modifier) but not in other types contexts (e.g. with %d
>   modifier). Since PHP 5.2.0, converting objects without __toString()
>   method to string would cause E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.

Comment: This doesn't seem the be case. It's a bug with PHP and debugger; see my "duplicate" flag.

Comment: I don't see your duplicate flag.  However I will confirm that this absolutely is the case in some environments.  The cause of this issue, at least in the case that I found, tested, and verified, had to do with trying to evaluate an object (instance of a class) as a string.  It is not a bug because PHP has it clearly documented: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: The docs also state that this behavior changed starting with PHP 5.2.  I'll update my answer to include the snippet from http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: Actually I want to backtrack a little bit.  While I believe these issues are coupled/directly related, it appears that the warning I am describing is not exactly the same as the OP.  I also found this comment on the PHP docs that describes the OPs exact issue: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.param-count.php#89490

Answer (score 0):

I got *Property access is not allowed yet* when running tests inside PhpStorm. I had the project's *PHP Lanugage Level* set to 7.2 and the *CLI Interpreter* set to 7.1. I changed the interpreter to 7.4 and the error went away.