# Property access not allowed yet when using mysqli_init(). Trying to skip secure auth in php

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli, my.cnf

I'm trying to skip secure authentication in php.

```
$con= mysqli_init();
mysqli_options( $con, "READ_MYSQLI_DEFAULT_FILE", "/etc/my.cnf" );
mysqli_real_connect( $con, "localhost", ....password,etc... )
```

When i debug in phpstorm, on the first line, mysqli_init fails and says property access is not allowed yet..

Comment: How do you debug this? I suppose PhpStorm is showing `access is not allowed yet..` message after static code inspection. Can you please show bigger piece of your code? Did you get any PHP errors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after finding this answer on SO: [mysqli + xdebug breakpoint after closing statment result in many warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377030/mysqli-xdebug-breakpoint-after-closing-statment-result-in-many-warnings)

it looks like its a bug in the mysqli driver, there was nothing wrong with the code or the connection however.