# Warning about WordPress and the function mysqli_init()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

Version and environment:

- Apache/2.4.7 (Win64)
- PHP/5.5.23
- TS,VC11 X64
- mysqli : mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503

When I open the WordPress page, a warning would display:

```
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_init(): Property access is not allowed yet in
D:\amp\www\localhost\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1363 Call
Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.2010  239016  {main}()...\index.php:0
2   0.2020  242152  require('D:\amp\www\localhost\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php' )   ...\index.php:21
3   0.2020  260504  require_once('D:\amp\www\localhost\wordpress\wp-load.php')  ...\wp-blog-header.php:12
4   0.2050  272024  require_once('D:\amp\www\localhost\wordpress\wp-config.php' )   ...\wp-load.php:38
5   0.2080  371352  require_once('D:\amp\www\localhost\wordpress\wp-settings.php')  ...\wp-config.php:87
6   0.2400  2151376 require_wp_db() ...\wp-settings.php:119
7   0.2440  2481160 wpdb->__construct(string(4), string(4), string(9), string(9) )  ...\load.php:362
8   0.2450  2482824 wpdb->db_connect( ??? ) ...\wp-db.php:612
9   0.2460  2483016 mysqli_init ( ) ...\wp-db.php:1363
```

How can I solve this question?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401923/property-access-not-allowed-yet-when-using-mysqli-init-trying-to-skip-secure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377030/mysqli-xdebug-breakpoint-after-closing-statment-result-in-many-warnings?

Comment: thanks I tried to use the php_mysqli.dll(ver. 5.5.12)  I extracted from wampserver with Apache 2.4.9 PH 5.5.12 Mysql 5.6.17 to replace the current file , but It‘s not work.finaly I installed the wampserver,and it's operating normally.The http server is not production environment,because I just want to read and learn source code of WordPress . It is strange that the legacy version could run well