# Warning: mysqli::init(): Property access is not allowed yet in [script path]

Tags: php, mysqli, typo3, xdebug

I have installed a fresh new Typo3 installation.
I have Windows 7 and use Apache 2.4
PHP 5.6.11 with Zend Engine 2.6.0 and with Xdebug v2.3.3.

Typo3 uses their own error handler so it is possible to control the error levels in the configuration file. However the mysqli still throws warnings for `mysqli::init()` and `mysqli::stmt_init()`. In both cases the error are

> PHP Warning: mysqli::stmt_init(): Property access is not allowed yet in W:\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Database\DatabaseConnection.php on line 782
>
> PHP Warning: mysqli_init(): Property access is not allowed yet in W:\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Database\DatabaseConnection.php line 1190

I have tried to read the thread [mysqli + xdebug breakpoint after closing statment result in many warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377030/mysqli-xdebug-breakpoint-after-closing-statment-result-in-many-warnings) but it seems the warning is related to some bugs in mysqli. As what I read these bugs should be resolved. 
Since these errors comes from the core of Typo3 I think it will be foolish to edit in the DatabaseConnection.php file. 
However, I have tested my connection using `mysqli::__construct` instead of `mysqli_init()`. `mysqli::__construct` does not throw any warnings/errors.   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

In typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php I have set `errorHandlerErrors` and `exceptionalErrors` to 30965 instead of 30466 such that Typo3 does not trows an exception for warnings. This only solved the problem for `mysqli_init()` - not `stmt_init()`.

So what can I do?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version?

Comment: @Jost: It is  6.2.18 and 6.2.25

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by set the error reporting level to E_ALL except E_STRICT in php.ini.
That is because the built in error handler in Typo3 is more sensitive that default error handler.

`error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);`